# Famo.us: How to put form fields inside a scrolling view that works on iOS and Safari?

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, famo.us

I’m trying to create a scrolling form for a mobile web app using a Famous ScrollView. However, iOS exhibits severe display bugs when scrolling while the keyboard is active. This occurs whether using an [InputSurface](http://jsfiddle.net/byC98/12/) or embedding an `<input>` [directly in the Surface HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/byC98/13/).

What’s the best way to achieve a scrollable input form that supports Mobile Safari?

(JSFiddle code replicated below; to see the bug, tap on a text field and then attempt to scroll while keyboard is active.)

```
Famous.loaded(function () {
    var Engine = Famous.Core.Engine;
    var Surface = Famous.Core.Surface;
    var Scrollview = Famous.Views.Scrollview;
    var Transform = Famous.Core.Transform;

    var mainContext = Engine.createContext();

    var scrollview = new Scrollview();
    var surfaces = [];

    scrollview.sequenceFrom(surfaces);

    var inputhtml = '<div><input type="text" value="test: edit me" /></div>';

    for (var i = 0, temp; i < 40; i++) {
        temp = new Surface({
            content: inputhtml,
            size: [undefined, 200],
            properties: {
                backgroundColor: "hsl(" + (i * 360 / 40) + ", 100%, 50%)",
                lineHeight: "200px",
                textAlign: "center"
            },
            index: i
        });

        temp.pipe(scrollview);
        surfaces.push(temp);
    }
    mainContext.add(scrollview);
});
```

Comment: please let me know if you can re-produce the bug via simulator - go to browserstack.com - sign up  an account - enter url test as : prollygeek.com/ios/ - try scrolling after keyboard shows up , if the issue appears please try to record behaviour , if not , let me know so i can get a real iphone and try to help you , cheers.

Comment: @ProllyGeek Tested, issue's still there. It will almost certainly need an actual device or the iOS Simulator to see the issue, since it's an interaction problem rather than a static rendering problem.

Comment: can you see the issue on the simulator ? if so i recommend using http://app.crossbrowsertesting.com/test-center , they have a tool to record videos , else if it doesnt show up , i will try getting an iphone by tonight to solve this issue.

Comment: tested the page on real iphone , the only issue i can see is the text cursor lag when you scroll , correct ? are there any other issues im not aware of ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek Are you looking at iOS7/8? The scrolling stutters and judders, the cursor jumps around, and the scroller permanently loses state, making certain portions of the scrollview unreachable.

Comment: iOS 8.1 , same what happens on emulator happens on real phone , have you tried any other phone with different version ?

Comment: Tried many different devices, real and simulated. Click into a text box and spend some time dragging back and forth, and you should see the problem. It gets worse when the finger drag starts in the text box, and/or drags over the keyboard.

Comment: Best solution is to record a video for exact bug.

Comment: Good idea: https://vid.me/Q86J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that famous scroll view is not truly scrollable , they animate the group so that it looks smooth , and to add the **[pull to refresh effect](http://pnc.co.il/dev/iscroll-5-pull-to-refresh-and-infinite-demo.html)**.

**A solution for this** : there is no really a direct and neat solution for this as the iOS keyboard animation will always focus into input and on the other hand famous uses a hidden indicator that works like a scroll bar , which conflicts with the iOS focus algorithm , so the only possible solution is that famous changes the way they animate scrollable view.

**Workaround:**

- Fortunately there is workaround , if user will scroll away from input
  it means they may be not interested in inputting text anymore , so we
  can blur the target input once the view is scrolled.
- after lot of searching I didnt really find a rigid event for famous to indicate scroll start event, however mutation observer worked well to achieve the required result.

> Famo.us ScrollView MouseOver - jsFiddle demo
>
> ```
>   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
>
>
>       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/jperl/famous-compiled/e9c12b1fa657820d3f9bad093ea72e8ee2dfec46/dist/lib/famous/core/famous.css">
>
>
>
>       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
>       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://rawgit.com/jperl/famous-compiled/e9c12b1fa657820d3f9bad093ea72e8ee2dfec46/dist/src/4f231991.polyfills.js"></script>
>
>       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/jperl/famous-compiled/97f85aaa64af255adfe0407c941e0e859b0759bc/dist/src/804b0adb.main.js"></script>
>
>
>   <style>
>     input { font-size: 40px; }
>   </style>
>
>
>
> <script type="text/javascript">
> var observer;
> window.onload=function(){
> Famous.loaded(function () {
>     var Engine = Famous.Core.Engine;
>     var Surface = Famous.Core.Surface;
>     var Modifier = Famous.Core.Modifier;
>     var Scrollview = Famous.Views.Scrollview;
>     var Transform = Famous.Core.Transform;
>
>     var mainContext = Engine.createContext();
>
>     var scrollview = new Scrollview();
>     var surfaces = [];
>
>     scrollview.sequenceFrom(surfaces);
>
>     var inputhtml = '<div><input type="text" value="test: edit me" /></div>';
>
>     for (var i = 0, temp; i < 40; i++) {
>         temp = new Surface({
>             content: inputhtml,
>             size: [undefined, 200],
>             properties: {
>                 backgroundColor: "hsl(" + (i * 360 / 40) + ", 100%, 50%)",
>                 lineHeight: "200px",
>                 textAlign: "center"
>             },
>             index: i
>         });
>
>         temp.pipe(scrollview);
>         surfaces.push(temp);
>     }
>     mainContext.add(scrollview);
>
> });
> $("body").on("focus","input",function(){Observe($(this));});
> $("body").on("blur","input",function(){endObserver();})
> }
>
>
> function Observe(event_input)
> {
>   var target = document.querySelector('.famous-group');
>
> // create an observer instance
> observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
>   mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
>     event_input.blur();
>     console.log(mutation.oldValue);
>   });    
> });
>
> // configuration of the observer:
> var config = { attributes: true, attributeOldValue: true, characterData: true };
>
> // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
> observer.observe(target, config);
> }
> function endObserver()
> {
>   observer.disconnect();
> }
>
> </script>
>
>
> </head>
> <body>
> </body>
>
> </html>
> ```

The live example can be found on my **[page](http://prollygeek.com/ios/)**

Comment: It's not the fix I was hoping for, but it's the best I'm gonna be able to get until Famo.us fixes the root problem. :/ Thanks!

Comment: @Luke Dennis maybe if you tell me why you are using famous after all , then we can find a better solution , or maybe we can replace this part in your app to be pure native , cheers

Comment: At this point, it's to avoid having to re-do the app from scratch. ;) It's a cool platform in general, but it still has a ways to go before I'd use it in production again.

Answer (score 2):

This code seems to fix it by forcing a redraw of the text areas.

```
<style>
    input.force-redraw {
      text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0) 0px 0px 0px;
    }
</style>
<script>
    setInterval(function(){ 
        $('input').toggleClass('force-redraw');
    }, 10);
</script>
```

Updated fiddles:
http://jsfiddle.net/byC98/87/
http://jsfiddle.net/byC98/88/

Unfortunately this is more of a hack then a fix :(

CPU utilization on an old laptop:
[image]

This is a modified version of rooby's code from https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/issues/178#issuecomment-11941817

Comment: Alas, this doesn't seem to fix it on iOS Safari.